# How can I divide cells into two parts in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

For example I want to divide cell B2 into two parts, *without* inserting any new row or column. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of workbook, how lovely]

Comment: I want to divide a cell into two or more parts which should also let me select the divided part of the cell.

Comment: Hi ramji, welcome to Super User. Thanks for the screenshot to illustrate what you would like, but I don't understand how it shows what you want. Can you make it any clearer?

Comment: @bertieb the screenshot shows a cell that has 2 parts. I wonder how you achieved that though as to my knowledge that is not possible. Did you draw that line yourself perhaps?

Comment: @LPChip oh, my mistake- could not see that (bad eyesight), thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I am pretty sure Excel does not have a unit smaller than a single cell.  You could achieve this by merging B&C for all rows except row 2.  How about explaining why you want this, there may be alternative approaches.

Comment: Dear bertieb you can see in the screenshoot that b2 cell has been divided into two parts. I want to do this in any cell, namely i want to part a cell two or more parts.

Comment: I would have the arrow pointing at the *division* myself, but point taken ;)

Comment: Dear paul I am creating a some kind of form on excel which have lot of text and also mathematical calculations so to adjust the text with mathematical calculation I am in dire need of something like which have been shown in screenshoot.

Comment: Friends as far as I know nothing is impossible in ms excel. I have asked many questions on superuser regarding excel and each question was answered perfectly. I think this question is easier than those of earlier asked. So please help me..

Comment: I know excel provides the facility to merge two cells but does it also provide the facility to part a cell.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to split an Excel cell into smaller parts (rows, columns).

This concept exists in Word tables or in html, but not in Excel.

When designing a spreadsheet you need to start from the smallest unit in a table, which is a cell.  As discussed in the comments to your question, you can merge cells to span several rows or several columns.

Merged cells introduce problems with aspects of data selection, though, so use them with caution. Instead of merging cells across several columns, it is often better to use the cell alignment "Center across selection".

Comment: @Baron, pray please tell me how you split a cell in Excel into smaller parts. Post that as an answer and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: The page explains how to merge split cells,  http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000874.htm

Comment: @Baron And there you have it. They show how to merge cells. They show how to split merged cells back into single cells. But there is NO WAY to split a single cell that is not part of a merged cell. Please read the question and understand the problem before shooting down a correct answer. I suggest you take back your downvote.

Comment: please forgive me. You're absolutely correct. I must've misunderstood. Also, I was not ignoring responding, I am just very busy. Again, I sincerely apologize.